# Python - Concat the output of join() method

Tags: python, for-loop, psycopg2, mysql-connector

In python + psycopg2 is it possible to transform this line of code that use an in-line for loop :

```
args_str = ','.join(cur_psql.mogrify("(%(customer_id)s, %(customer_name)s, %(contact_name)s, %(address)s, %(city)s, %(postal_code)s, %(country)s)", row) for row in cur_msql)
```

Into a piece of code that **permit to make more operations** while iterating the for loop, but still obtaining the same output(a single object containing all the data -> args_str) ? Eg.:

```
for row in cur_msql:
  # additional operations eg.:
  if row['customer_name'] == NULL:
    row['customer_name'] = row['customer_name']
  args_str =+ ','.join(cur_psql.mogrify("(%(customer_id)s, %(customer_name)s, %(contact_name)s, %(address)s, %(city)s, %(postal_code)s, %(country)s)", row)
```

Comment: Other than needing `+=` instead of `=+`, what's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code accumulates in a list each of the "mogrified" values and then uses `join()` to put them together afterwards:

```
args = []
for row in cur_msql:
    # additional operations eg.:
    if row['customer_name'] == NULL:
        row['customer_name'] = row['customer_name']
    args.append(cur_psql.mogrify("(%(customer_id)s, %(customer_name)s, %(contact_name)s, %(address)s, %(city)s, %(postal_code)s, %(country)s)", row))

args_str = ','.join(args)
```

It should create an equivalent `args_str` to:

```
args_str = ','.join(cur_psql.mogrify("(%(customer_id)s, %(customer_name)s, %(contact_name)s, %(address)s, %(city)s, %(postal_code)s, %(country)s)", row) for row in cur_msql)
```

(N.B. I changed `x` to `row` in the above.)

Whether that string is actually what you need/want is another question.